# R Repeating column and row headers

Tags: r, header

I have 100 csv files in a folder and have been asked to write a function which will return the number of complete cases for each file (a count for all rows which contain 0 NA values). In each file there are 5 columns.

I am trying to return a data frame which will show the 'ID' column (gives reference to the file) and the calculated 'Nobs' column (gives the number of complete cases in each csv file). I want to be able to do this for different files, specified in the function eg: files 1:3, 78:92 etc.

I am able to get the correct figure for number of complete cases and the corresponding ID number, but when I paste by function the column headers 'ID' and Nobs' are repeated after each line (please see below). I want the column headers at the top of each column only, not to be repeated after each row.

```
  ID Nobs
1  2 1042
  ID Nobs
1  4  475
  ID Nobs
1  8  193
  ID Nobs
1 10  149
  ID Nobs
1 12   97
```

Please can you help me with this.
Summary: How would you get rid of the repeating headers 'ID' and 'Nobs' after each row.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code here so I created my own simple example which you can adjust.

I've created 2 csv files with names `dt1.csv` and `dt2.csv`. Each of them has 3 rows, but only `dt1.csv` has one row with NA in one of the columns.

```
# vector of file names
filenames = list.files(pattern = "[.]csv")

library(dplyr)

data.frame(filenames, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%            # create dataframe with the file names
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%                            # add the id
  group_by(filenames) %>%                                  # for each filename
  do({dd = read.csv(.$filenames)                           # read the csv file
      data.frame(.,                                        # keep file name and id
                 Nobs = nrow(dd[complete.cases(dd),]))})   # count number of complete cases

# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# Groups: filenames [2]
# 
#    filenames    id  Nobs
#        (chr) (int) (int)
# 1   dt1.csv     1     2
# 2   dt2.csv     2     3
```